# Moving picture box with click

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm looking to put an image from one picture box into another with a click on the picture box, but only if an int value = 0, any help would be much appreciated!!

Here's my code

```
    private void pictureBox_Uncooked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Open_Count == 0)
        {
            pictureBox_Micro.Image = pictureBox_Uncooked.Image;
            pictureBox_Uncooked.Image = null;
        }      
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: he means, you should not only **write** this method, instead, you should **select** `pictureBox_Uncooked` in designer, then goto properties window, select events, and **generate** Click event code.

Comment: Your code works fine. Are you sure `Open_Count` is getting set to `0`? Is there an `Image` loaded in `pictureBox_Micro`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Design page, Select the Picture Box(`pictureBox_Uncooked`) and click `F4` properties will appears.

Here goto the Events area. There you have to doubleclick the click event for the picture box

then goto codebehind window or click `F7`. There you can see the method, there you can implemet your code. it will works.

another thing is.
Initially ,You need to check the `Open_Count` value is  `Zero` or not .If it is zero ,then the if condition works properly.